# Factory pattern in library, allow for registering implementations

Tags: java, factory

I've got a question about using a factory pattern in my library.

I'm making a library, which includes some tests and interfaces. For these interfaces, I've written tests that use mock-classes. But I also want to apply these tests to all my implementations.

Let's say one of my tests looks like this.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Date now = new Date();
    IFace iFace= new MockClass(now);
    assertEquals(now, iFace.getNow());
}
```

Now I want to be able to run this test on all implementations that I write of IFace. My thoughts were to write something like this:

```
private ArrayList<IFaceProvider> iFaceProviders= new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<IFace> produceAll(){
    ArrayList<IFace> iFaces = new ArrayList<>();
    for (IFaceProvider iFaceProvider:iFaceProviders){
        iFaces.add(iFaceProvider.provide());
    }
    return iFaces;
}
```

For every implementation I make, I make a `iFaceProvider` which I then register to my factory. The `iFaceProvider` could have something like `provideIf(String string)` or so, so that my factory could provide a specific implementation.

Would this be a good way to do this? Or are there simpler ways to do this?

Edit:

I figured I'd just go ahead and write one implementation of this, to explain my idea better:

```
package nl.buroboot.danielvandenberg;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class Factory<ToCreate,CreateFrom> {
    private ArrayList<FactoryCreator<ToCreate,CreateFrom>> factoryCreators = new ArrayList<>(); 

    public ToCreate create(CreateFrom createFrom){
        return create(0,createFrom);
    }

    public ToCreate create(int i, CreateFrom createFrom){
        return create(factoryCreators.get(i),createFrom);
    }

    public ToCreate create(FactoryCreator<ToCreate,CreateFrom> factoryCreator,CreateFrom createFrom){
        if (factoryCreator == null){
            return null;
        }
        return factoryCreator.from(createFrom);
    }

    public int addFactoryCreator(FactoryCreator<ToCreate,CreateFrom> appointmentLocationCreator){
        if (!factoryCreators.contains(appointmentLocationCreator)){
            factoryCreators.add(appointmentLocationCreator);
        }
        return factoryCreators.indexOf(appointmentLocationCreator);
    }

    public interface FactoryCreator<ToCreate,CreateFrom>{
        public ToCreate from(CreateFrom createFrom);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to make factory operate on ***enum*** rather than String.

Comment: @John I already changed it to a fully generic implementation. However, enums do not always work. For instance, if I'd want to make a "Location" from an enum, I'd have to make an enum for every single address. A string would be more generic, as it would allow me to simply input "Somestreet 123, SomeCity"

Answer (score 0):

Check out parameterized tests with Junit.  It lets you repeat tests while changing a little bit of test data, which in your case could be the specific implementation you want to test.  You could construct that list from your list of iFaceProviders.

The feature is documented [on the JUnit Wiki](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests) and here is an example from [one of my projects](https://github.com/lmcalpin/sidrat/blob/master/sidrat-test/src/test/java/com/sidrat/BaseRecorderTest.java) where I apply a set of tests over a set of implementations.